# Regular Expression to extract string after seeing "number + one letter + [comma or whitespace]" in Bigquery

Tags: sql, regex, nlp, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract:

Abbey Grove
Abbey Grove
Abbey Road View
Abbey Road
Abbey Terrace
Abbey Wood Road
Abbey Grove

from

```
23a, Abbey Grove
43a Abbey Grove
Block 509a Abbey Road View
511 Abbey Road
Flat 8a, Abbey Terrace
14 Abbey Wood Road
100 Abbey Grove
```

in Google Bigquery. The issue is that:

```
regexp_replace(text, '[^a-zA-Z]', '')
```

gives me "aabbeywood" with two a's. Essentially I just want to keep all the text after a "numeric" or "numeric plus one letter" string.

Comment: Can you add more examples of inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(t, '.*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]?[^a-zA-Z]*', '') FROM UNNEST(['23a, Abbey Grove','43a Abbey Grove','Block 509a Abbey Road View','511 Abbey Road','Flat 8a, Abbey Terrace','14 Abbey Wood Road','100 Abbey Grove']) t
```

I tried to reproduce the problem with your data. For this specific data it worked in `BigQuery`.

This regex can be translated as:

1. Search for any characters zero or more times
2. Search for numbers one or more times
3. Search for zero or one letters between a and z (lower or upper)
4. Search for any character that is not a letter zero or more times

You you have some different cases where this regex doesnt apply, please let me know.
I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy because I don't know all your constraints (e.g. Can street names contain numbers? Can there be other words than "Block" before the number?). Here is a regex that works for the given examples (you can get street names from `group3`):

```
^(Block ){0,1}([0-9]+[A-Z|a-z]{0,1}[,]{0,1} )([a-z|A-Z| ]+)
```

See [this link](https://regex101.com/r/MpVSGZ/1) for an example.

Comment: Thanks Thibauld, yes, there can be other words besides Block but no there cannot be any numbers in the street names

Comment: *I have updated the second block to "flat" to make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this maybe it helps you.

> 1) Create one function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveChars(@Input varchar(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @pos INT
  SET @Pos = PATINDEX('%[^a-z A-Z]%',@Input)
  WHILE @Pos > 0
   BEGIN
    SET @Input = STUFF(@Input,@pos,1,'')
    SET @Pos = PATINDEX('%[^a-z A-Z]%',@Input)
   END
  RETURN @Input
END
GO
```

**After creating function run below query**

```
DECLARE @Tabel TABLE(
    Text VARCHAR(250)
)

INSERT INTO @Tabel 
VALUES('23a, Abbey Grove'),
('43a Abbey Grove'),
('Block 509a Abbey Road View'),
('511 Abbey Road'),
('Block 8a, Abbey Terrace'),
('14 Abbey Wood Road'),
('100 Abbey Grove')

SELECT dbo.RemoveChars(Text) AS Text FROM @Tabel
```

Comment: Thank you Jishan, I don't think this code works in bigquery?

Comment: Yes I know it's not working in the big query or slow down performance but we can do one thing when we store data in table we can put another filed in table and parse data stored with as expected output when we select data use we created filed without any process :)

Comment: I do agree, but the specification was to extract in bigquery :-p

Comment: Ok, I'm trying once I do than let you know :).